# TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSelect' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement react big calendar however I am having an issue with adding an event and using set state to update the event. I brought in the handleselect function inside the Selectable constructor but when I try to use it I get the following error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSelect' of undefined

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css";
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation";
import events from "./events";
import { Calendar, momentLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar";
import moment from "moment";

const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment);

class Selectable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { events };
  }

  handleSelect = ({ start, end }) => {
    const title = window.prompt("New Event name");

    alert("title " + title);

    if (title) {
      console.log("testing");


      this.setState({
        events: [
          this.state.events,
          {
            start,
            end,
            title,
          },
        ],
      });

      console.log(events);
    }
  };

}

const MyCalendar = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Navigation />
    <Calendar
      selectable
      localizer={localizer}
      events={events}
      popup
      startAccessor="start"
      endAccessor="end"
      style={{ height: 700 }}
      onSelectSlot={this.handleSelect}
    />
  </div>
);
export default MyCalendar;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.handleSelect
```

'this' is outside of scope. Try moving your function inside Select class!

After you will see the result, may be you will get an idea of what has happened. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `MyCalendar` and `Selectable` are two different components.

On `MyCalendar` you're trying to read some values from the `this` object but, since it's and arrow function with no upper scope, `this` is `undefined`.

Bear in mind the `Selectable` component has no render function in it.